# "ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-rocksdb" when building Docker Container

Tags: python, dockerfile, rocksdb

For my project, I run a Docker Container which needs to have python-rocksdb installed. This usually worked for me, but since 1 or 2 weeks, the building process fails with "... Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: rocksdb/_rocksdb.pyx ------------------ ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-rocksdb".
This is a simplified version of my Dockerfile that reproduces this error:

```
FROM python:3.10.2-buster
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    python-dev \
    librocksdb-dev \
    build-essential \
    cmake
RUN pip3 install python-rocksdb
```

I experimented with different images, the installations in the Dockerfile and I also tried to install rocksdb from source. All result in the same error. Would be happy if anyone could help :)

Comment: Check rocksdb docs for compatibility. You might be able to resolve this by changing either python or rocksdb version. When that happens on my projects, that usually solves the problem, in most cases.